# How do I clear a global variable that also is buffer-local?

Tags: hooks, buffer-local

I called `add-hook` multiple times because I had a few typos in the hook function, and now there are a bunch of broken copies of it in the hook.

I want to do `(setq after-save-hook nil)`, but after doing `describe-variable` on `after-save-hook`, I see this:

```
Original value was nil
Local in buffer driver.z80; global value is 
((lambda nil
   (if
       (string=
        (buffer-name)
        "driver.z80")
       (compile "build.bat")))
 (lambda nil
   (if
       (string=
        (buffer-name "driver.z80"))
       (compile "build.bat")))
 (lambda nil
   (if
       (string=\?
        (buffer-name "driver.z80"))
       (compile "build.bat")))
 (lambda nil
   (if
       (string=\?
        (buffer-name "driver.z80")
        (compile "build.bat"))))
 rmail-after-save-hook)
```

And no matter what I do I can't seem to clear this out. Any suggestions?

Comment: For buffer-local-variables, I like to use `setq-default` for the global value and `setq-local` for the buffer-local value.

Comment: Looks like `setq-default` was what I was after. Thanks!

Comment: Many users recommend adding/removing functions to hooks that have their own names, rather than `(lambda ...)` as it makes inspecting and managing a little easier with `add-hook` / `remove-hook`....

Comment: Is buffer-local really relevant to the problem you encountered? If so, how so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What @lawlist said in a comment:

*Do not put lambda forms on hooks* (avoid that, at least).  It is **so** much easier to provide a named function to `remove-hook` than to try to provide it the exact lambda form you provided to `add-hook`.

---

That said, you've already done it. ;-) What you need to do now is to do `C-h v`, as you've done, and then select the printed text for one of the lambda forms and pass it to `remove-hook`. Then do the same with each of the other lambda forms.

---

One thing I do sometimes when I'm experimenting with some code: For each `add-hook` I write and play with I put a corresponding `remove-hook` in a buffer (e.g. `*scratch*`), to be able to easily evaluate to cancel that hook function.

(Similarly, sometimes when I use `debug-on-entry` I put a `(cancel-debug-on-entry)` sexp somewhere easy to evaluate.)

Comment: Any reason it was so hard to reset the variable to just `nil`? Using `setq` seemed to do nothing, and only `setq-default` actually changed the value seen when I used `C-h v`, and I think it screwed somethings up because then `add-hook` wouldn't add stuff to it.

Comment: `setq` changes only the buffer-local value of a variable, if there is a local value, which it is here. Did you use a non-nil 4th arg to `add-hook`, to affect only the local value?